# Changing the HTML button color in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have a javascript function to change the inner HTML of a button according to a function.

Javascript

```
function event_click_startpause( event ){
              if( interval === null ){
                  start();
                  event.target.innerText = 'pause';}
              else {
                  pause();
                  event.target.innerText = 'Resume';}
                  }
              function start(){
                 pause();
                 interval = setInterval( count, 1000 );
              function pause() {
                 clearInterval( interval );
                 interval = null; }
                                        }
```

HTML

```
<button id="pause" class="pause">Pause</button>
```

CSS

```
.pause{
background: #c1580b;
color: #ffb734;
width: 70px;
height: 70px;
line-height: 70px;
display: block;
border-radius: 50%;
text-align: center;
text-decoration:none;
border:2px solid #000;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px #c1580b;
font-size: medium;
}
```

So here how can I change the background color of the button to green when changing inner HTML of the button to "resume"?

Comment: I would create another CSS block for Resume, then just change the elements className attribute in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://jsfiddle.net/xb0yncj7/1/ -

```
var interval = null;
var count = function() {};

window.event_click_startpause = function(btn) {
    if (interval === null) {
        start();
        btn.innerText = 'pause';
        btn.style.backgroundColor = "#F00"
    } else {
        pause();
        btn.innerText = 'Resume';
        btn.style.backgroundColor = "#0F0";
    }

    function start() {
        pause();
        interval = setInterval(count, 1000);

    }

    function pause() {
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but this is not working on jsfiddle

Comment: Sorry - I didn't save my updates - see https://jsfiddle.net/xb0yncj7/1/

Answer (score 2):

You could change the background color

```
 event.target.css('background-color','#ff00ff');
```

Answer (score 2):

Though not clear from your JS above, assuming you have the button store as a DOM element in JS, you can use the `style` method chained with the property of your choosing:

`event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'green'`

Note: properties are called via camelCase

Comment: It is possible then that your `event` data is not a DOM element

Answer (score 2):

```
let pauseButton = document.getElementById('pause');    
pauseButton.classList.add('green');
```

and on you style add

```
.pause.green {
    background: green;
}
```

or use

```
let pauseButton = document.getElementById('pause');
pauseButton.style.background = 'green';
```

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xb0yncj7/2/) of the working background color. Let me know if it works for you.